# How can I verify if the quantity of fuel being used is correct?

Tags: refueling

Is there a formula to determine if the quantity of aviation fuel that is posted as being used is correct? If I have the number of gallons, the pounds and hours flown?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I don't completely understand your question. What is the "posted" value that you're talking about? Exactly what two things are you trying to compare?

Comment: Posted ***where***?

Answer (score 1):

The fuel for a typical GA aircraft is AvGas, 100LL (blue tint).
It weighs 6.01 lbs / gallon.

`Gallons * 6.01` is the weight.  For example, if you're filling up a Cessna 172SP that holds 56 gallons, it should take 336.5 lbs. of fuel.

To calculate how much has consumed, you'll have to know the burn-rate of your airplane. Again, using a 172SP, the published burn rate is 13 g/hr, but most people lean to about 10 g/hr.  So you can expect that, per hour flown, the plane should use about 60 lbs. of fuel.

Of course, a plane will use more climbing, less descending, and a certain amount for ground operations.  So the exact details will depend on your flight profile.